# mx notifier email link/path to image broken

Tags: email, notification

when my email notification is sent when I create and entry using mx_notifier any images that are from an entry's text area field do not have the full path.

ie: they display as src="/images/uploads/pic.jpg"

instead of http://www.domain.com/images/uploads/pic.jpg

any way to change the src link to an image easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notify templates just take regular EE tags, don't they? Assuming they also support other add-on tags, could you use [Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace) to search for src="/ and replace with src="{site_url}/ ?

It supports regex too if you need to get a bit fancier with what you need replaced, especially given the likelihood that you'd need to include quotes in what's found/replaced.

Comment: that sounds like it would work well.  You are right in that I need to replace quotes.  Any tips on how this can be done with regex?

Answer (score 0):

BAM!

```
{exp:low_replace find="src=QUOTE/" replace="src=QUOTEhttp://domain.com/"} {exp:ez_image_resize:run max_width="500" quality="100"} {content} {/exp:ez_image_resize:run} {/exp:low_replace}
```